# given a point cloud of n points, create a convex shape that defines their outer limits

Tags: graph-theory

I have a point cloud. 
I find its 'centre' by averaging the coordinates of each point.
I translate the cloud so the average is at the origin (for simplicity sake)

I want to then create a convex shape such that those points are either on its surface or within the shape.

My questions are: 
Is this soluble without brute force?
What do I need to read/understand/search for to learn how to solve this problem.
IE is there a theorem that covers this precise problem.

Cheers

Comment: As a total outsider to the field, I’d say that this is one of the core problems of linear programming. But in what format is your set going to be described? By a bunch of linear inequalities, perhaps?

Comment: Firstly, please edit your title to say "convex" instead of "concave". Secondly, this is called finding the convex hull. There is an efficient algorithm for it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick%E2%80%93Seidel_algorithm .

Comment: Thank you very much jef. That mistake was just a momentary fudge. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **Convex Hull**. It is computable efficiently, see here for instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I am looking for. Sometimes it is hard to find the right thing to read if you don't have some starting knowledge. I will accept this answer when the time has elapsed.